# useState not updated as expected

Tags: reactjs

I have two components, one placed inside the other. The children component prints the state passed by the parent and updates the state once with useEffect. In the parent component I'm using setState (an object with boolean values) and passing the state to all the children.

Parent component:

```
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    one: false,
    two: false,
    three: false
  });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <ChildComponent
        value={state.one}
        setState={(val) => setState({ ...state, one: val })}
      />
      <ChildComponent
        value={state.two}
        setState={(val) => setState({ ...state, two: val })}
      />
      <ChildComponent
        value={state.three}
        setState={(val) => setState({ ...state, three: val })}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Child Component:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function ChildComponent({ value, setState }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("updated");
    setState(!value);
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <p>{value ? "true" : "false"}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Both components are really simple, and I'm expecting to see all boolean values being true (because the child components are modifying the state). The problem is that only the last item on the state is being updated. Can someone explain what is wrong with my code?
[A working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-field-88kiv)

Comment: it first looks I thought this is a beginner's mistake, but this is actually a tricky one

Comment: Related: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11527#issuecomment-360199710

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The state update is dependent on the previous value of the state, you need to pass a callback as the argument for your `setState` instead.

You need to do this instead:

```
setState={(val) => setState(prev => ({ ...prev, one: val }))}
```

In your current implementation, you're spreading the initial value of the state where everything is `false` instead of the current value of the state.

Example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/usestate-callback-1oq2n?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I've tried that but it didn't worked in my example. Tried again and it works lol. Too much time in front of the code I suppose. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Edit: you can handle it as @koralarts suggested, but if you want to understand why it happened,read this.

let's explore what's happens in your example.

**TLDR**: you have to split the setState call to separate hook in the parent for each child component, or manage the state in the children if possible.
each time you calling setState in the effect react **schedules** this call, and not execute it directly.
you are calling 3 times the same setState function in the same render, and each time react schedules the call to the next render, therefore, overriding the previous schedule.

If possible, manage this state from the children, if not, use different useState for each child on the parent.

#### Explanetetion:

let's be aware of the different lifecycle of a react component:

- update call
- effects (useLayoutEffect and later useEffect)

you can read the complete explanation [here](https://github.com/Eliav2/how-react-hooks-work#render-cycle)(highly recommended).

see [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-moore-zm8sc?file=/src/App.js) sandbox(like yours with logs).

read the difference between 'render' and 'update' [here](https://github.com/Eliav2/how-react-hooks-work#definitions):

> **render** - React tree is created based on the current state, then the
> tree is passed to the renderer that will update the VDOM, and changes
> will be flushed into the browser's DOM. render cycle consists of few
> phases that will be explained later. when we say that a component '
> render' we are usually talking about the end of the render cycle,
> after changes are flushed into the browser's DOM.

> **update** - when we say that a component 'updates', we are saying that the function component body re-executed (with possibly different props).   is one of the
> phases of a render. multiple update cycles are possible during a
> render cycle. examples of the difference between update and render
> later.

now read this [important](https://github.com/Eliav2/how-react-hooks-work#super-important-notes) notes:

> Calling state hook from effect(like useEffect or useLayoutEffect) will
> cause React to schedule another render.

> Calling state hook from FC body will cause React to schedule another update call.

##### your case:

- update phase: parent
- update phase: children
- effect phase: children => setState call causing react to schedule another render on of the parent. this happens 3 times on each child in the same phase(useEffect) and each schedule overwrites the previous child's schedules.

Answer (score 0):

I think is because [asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#when-is-setstate-asynchronous) behaviour of `setState`, By the time it renders the `ChildComponent`, it still having the `old state` not the updated one. Like @koralarts answer, you have to use previous state to update the state.

Answer (score 0):

see what is happening here is, when you are sending the **state in the first child component, the *state.one is updated to true*** , but then, you move on to the second component, that is ***using the same previous state where *state.one was false**** and the same happens in the third case too.

so what you need to do is pass a callback of the new updated state to the function setState.

```
setState= {(val)=>{setState(currState => ({ ...currState, two: val })}}
```